# Adding a file template shortcut to right click menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I made a custom file template, but using it requires 4 actions: right click -> click new -> click java class -> select custom template from drop down.

Is there any way to make a custom group in the context menu of the IDE so it would work like this: right click -> click new -> click fooFileFromTemplate ? Or even better right click -> click new -> click myCustomTemplatesGroup -> click fooFileFromTemplate.

Basically I want to avoid having to chose the template from a drop down list if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it - the answer was to write a plugin for the IDE and add my own group of Actions.